# Can't remove execjs gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, uninstallation

I am using Ruby and I am having trouble removing a gem.  The gem is execjs.  Here is some background information.

```
rvm use @global
rvm gem list

Outputs...
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
execjs (1.2.9)
...

Running either of the following commands
rvm gem uninstall execjs
             OR
rvm gem uninstall execjs -v 1.2.9

outputs this
INFO:  gem "execjs" is not installed
```

So it showed the gem in the gem list, but when I go to uninstall it, it says that it isn't there.  I'm confused ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this command for remove any gem

```
     gem uninstall execjs -v=1.2.9
```

Hope it will work.